# jhipster bootswatch yo generator not installed

Tags: spring-boot, npm, jhipster

Good morning,

i want to add bootswatch module to change theme of jhipster project as needed. Following the guide https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-jhipster-bootswatch I installed the npm install -g generator-jhipster-bootswatch module successfully. I get an error when I run the next command yo jhipster-bootswatch

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKD61.png)

The output of the yo doctor command reveals no problems with this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWYsk.png)

Do you have any tips to resolve this message?

Comment: don't post screenshots for code, post the actual code

Comment: The screenshots contain the terminal output of the yo jhipster-bootswatch command, as anticipated